# CALL and RET don't work as expected

Tags: assembly, x86, return, stack, nasm

I still get lost with the stack related operations often and in this case the problem is the **RET** instruction, which pops a wrong address for the *eip* register. I use **NASM** and my code looks like this:

```
start:
    call GiveMeAHandler
    call GetCommandLine
    ret

GiveMeAHandler:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push edi
    push esi
    push dword -11
    call dword [F_GetStdHandle] ; It executes correctly and returns
    mov [StdHandler], eax ; StdHandler is stored in BSS
    add esp, 4
    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    ret ; This returns to some weird address

GetCommandLine:
    ; ...
    ; I don't get here because the function above wrong return
```

Maybe I have exaggerated a little with the `ebp, edi, esi` pushing and popping (they are not altered after all) but even if I remove them the `ret` instruction still returns a wrong address (*77AE7094*) instead of *0040100A*, where I call the second function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Windows uses the `stdcall` calling convention, where function arguments are pushed onto the stack (right to left), and the *callee* cleans up the stack. In other words, when `GetStdHandle` returns, the stack will already be restored to before your `push dword -11` instruction. Try removing the `add esp, 4` line and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I could see the retn 4 and removed my own stack cleaning. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at what NASM generates for `push dword -11`:

```
6AF5    push byte -0xb
```

So NASM took your `dword` and replaced it with a `byte` (which will be promoted to a `word` by the CPU, since a `word` is the smallest unit you can `push` onto the stack).
Why did it do that? Well, there's [an optimizer](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.22) which is enabled by default, and which will attempt to optimize the size of immediates.

Since you (understandably) thought you had pushed a `dword` and later add 4 to `esp` you end up with an unbalanced stack.

To stop this from happening you can either add a `strict` specifier, as in:

```
push strict dword -11
```

Or use the `-O0` option when assembling.

Comment: From the Intel Sofware Developer manual vol. 2, the `push` instruction: "The operand size (16, 32, or 64 bits) determines the amount by which the stack pointer is decremented (2, 4
or 8)." Assuming this is 32-bit code, the default operand size will be 32 bits, so the CPU will actually promote it to a `dword`.

Comment: `push byte -0xb` is just a compact encoding for the immediate of a dword `push`.  There's no `66` operand-size prefix so the default operand size of 32-bit applies in 32-bit mode, not the smallest available regardless of mode.  Anyway, forcing a less compact encoding for a dword push is not useful here.